# How to call the universal sentence encoder model in Python using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to find sentence similarities using the universal sentence encoding model. I have universal sentence encoder model form saved on the local drive. But I don't know how to call it through the code directly from the local drive below instead of calling it through the link in the code. Note that my OS is windows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3")
def get_features(texts):
    if type(texts) is str:
        texts = [texts]
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
        return sess.run(embed(texts))
get_features("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.I am a sentence for which I would like to get its embedding")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `hub.load` to load the Universal Sentence Encoder Model which is Saved to Drive.

For example, the `USE-5` Model is Saved in the Folder named `5` and its Folder structure is shown in the screenshot below, we can load the `Model` using the code mentioned below:

[image]

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embed = hub.load('5')

embeddings = embed([
    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
    "I am a sentence for which I would like to get its embedding"])

print(embeddings)
```

Output of the above code is :

```
tf.Tensor([[ 0.01305105 0.02235123 -0.03263275 ... -0.00565093 -0.04793027 -0.11492756] [ 0.05833394 -0.08185011 0.06890941 ... -0.00923879 -0.08695354 -0.0141574 ]], shape=(2, 512), dtype=float32)
```

The above code is equivalent to the code shown below which uses the URL to Load the USE-5.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5")

embeddings = embed([ 
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.", 
"I am a sentence for which I would like to get its embedding"])

print(embeddings)
```

Comment: thank you very much because you help me @ Tensorflow Warriors